# Converting Pandas Dataframe column object in MM:SS format to Datetime type?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, timedelta

```
0                18:30
1                24:50
2                33:21
3                28:39
4                27:30
5                21:26
6                16:42
7                16:48
8                26:07
9                18:13
10               27:15
11               24:33
12               29:43
13               NaN
14               NaN
15               NaN
16               24:58
17               26:14
18               27:36
19               33:27
Name: Minutes, dtype: object
```

I have a column named `Minutes` which represents minutes spent performing a task. The column is in `MM:SS` format with no milliseconds or hours. There are a few `Null` values for those who did not perform the task, which I would like to just replace with `00:00`. I've tried converting the column to `datetime` with

```
df['Minutes'] = df['Minutes'].apply(pd.to_datetime, format = '%M:%S', errors='coerce')
```

which gives me

```
1       1900-01-01 00:24:50
2       1900-01-01 00:33:21
3       1900-01-01 00:28:39
4       1900-01-01 00:27:30
5       1900-01-01 00:21:26
```

This is fine I guess, but my goal is to be able to perform sorts on these columns by the most amount of time spent on a task. After I apply the `pd.to_datetime`, the datatype of the column is still an object. And when I try to sort I'm faced with:

> KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
>  in 
> ----> 1 df.sort_values(by=df['Minutes'], ascending=True)
> ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in sort_values(self, by, axis, ascending, inplace, kind, na_position, ignore_index, key)
> 5453
> 5454             by = by[0]
> -> 5455             k = self._get_label_or_level_values(by, axis=axis)
> 5456
> 5457             # need to rewrap column in Series to apply key function
> ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in _get_label_or_level_values(self, key, axis)
> 1682             values = self.axes[axis].get_level_values(key)._values
> 1683         else:
> -> 1684             raise KeyError(key)
> 1685
> 1686         # Check for duplicates

Answer (score 0):

Replace the NaN values using

```
df.fillna('00:00')
```

Followed by:

```
df['Minutes'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Minutes'], format='%M:%S', errors='coerce')
```

Followed by:

```
df.sort_values('Minutes')  #Note Ascending is default
```

Comment: No they are converted to NAT's

Comment: Thanks! This worked for the sorting issue. The only question is how do I get it to just the MM:SS format without changing the dtype? Right now it is displayed as '1900-01-01 00:18:30' I would like it to be just 18:30 or 00:18:30.

Comment: The simplest way would be to not convert the Minutes column to datetimestamp.  So you would have two lines:  ```df.fillna('00:00')``` and ```df.sort_values('Minutes')```

Comment: It's not the same if you say a duration is zero or you say the duration is unknown (what NaN means here). And I think you shouldn't set unknown durations to zero, just to make some code work somehow. So, I think `NaT` is what you want in this case. Sorting works fine with it btw.

Comment: @MrFuppes, the op has stated "There are a few Null values for those who did not perform the task, which I would like to just replace with 00:00", therefore the answer I gavce, rather than the use of NAT

Answer (score 0):

`pd.to_datetime` with keyword `errors='coerce'` takes care of NaNs, it will leave `NaT` (not-a-time) for the unknown durations.

Also note that for sorting, you actually do not need to convert to datetime at all.

```
import pandas as  pd
# >>> pd.__version__
# 1.3.5
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'Minutes': ["27:15", "24:33", "29:43", "NaN", np.NaN, None]})

# you can do a df.sort_values('Minutes') here already!

df['Minutes'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Minutes'], format='%M:%S', errors='coerce')
df = df.sort_values('Minutes')

# df['Minutes']
# 1   1900-01-01 00:24:33
# 0   1900-01-01 00:27:15
# 2   1900-01-01 00:29:43
# 3                   NaT
# 4                   NaT
# 5                   NaT
# Name: Minutes, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

To change the *format*, you'll need to convert back to string:

```
df['Minutes'].dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
# 1    00:24:33
# 0    00:27:15
# 2    00:29:43
# 3         NaN
# 4         NaN
# 5         NaN
# Name: Minutes, dtype: object
```